# Bug found in windows memory diagnostic test, how to understand the memory dump and fix the issue?

Tags: windows-10, memory

This is an example:

> The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x00000050 (0xffffd2046f675d00, 0x0000000000000000, 0xfffff8067f1f1d49, 0x0000000000000002). A dump was saved in: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 70d14973-9a07-47af-a472-47d81fe8dc01

How this came?

By running windows memory diagnostic test.

This is the test:
[image: This is the test]

I followed this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XN1u40hkro4

But I'll tell what I did still.

First I did that above test. Then my windows 10 laptop restarted itself. Then I went to "event viewer".
Then I searched for "memory" and I keep on looking at everything that came. I saw these things.

[image: img1]

This is one example.

[image: img2]

This is the memory dump, it's 450 MB, not sure why it's so big(IDK if anyone would download such a huge file, please tell me other ways to send this file if you know). Hope there's no private information in it.

[Memory Dump File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yQIsruaSYLj0ZnJD4f--IJmZVmZF60Cd/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: "t's 450 MB, not sure why it's so big" - It's a memory dump it's suppose to be large, and 450 MB, is actually small. I am not up to the task to running WinDBG, what I can tell you, there isn't a bug in the memory diagnostic within Windows.  What is more likely is you have a hardware problem that is causing the restart. In order to confirm there is a hardware problem instead of a bug that likely does not exist I would run a more in-depth memory tester like memtestx86.  I assume Windows is crashing hence the reason you are running the memory check in the first place

Comment: I've only 1 8GB RAM, do I need to do the test?I mean it'd be that RAM which has failed if that's the case.

Comment: So you are performing a Windows Diagnostic Test, because, everything is fine and dandy? I think that’s unlikely. My advice would be to still run MemTestx86 to verify you actually do or don’t have a memory problem.  If you don’t have a problem then the system is likely crashing for a different reason

Comment: @Ramhound did memtest86, no errors.